# Remove drop-down menu for reload button in Firefox 4 and add drop-down menu for back button

Tags: firefox

The new drop-down menu added to the reload button in Firefox 4 which shows custom page reload times is useless. I would like to remove it, and just have the plain reload/stop button combo.

The old Firefox 3 style drop-down menu for the back button which showed a selected tab's browsing history (both back and forwards) is something I really would've liked to have seen continued.

Is there any way to achieve either/both of these configuration?

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

Comment: Ehm.. I have no idea what you're talking about. Over here, it's still all the way it used to be. Screenshot maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean regarding the reload button "dropdown"? On Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows Vista the reload button is just that - a reload/stop button at the end of the address bar (moved from the left side of the address bar in Firefox 3). There is no dropdown menu on the reload button.

In Firefox 4 the dropdown menu on the back button (and forward button) is activated by holding the mouse button down for about 1 second whilst over the back or forward buttons. This is the same behaviour as Google Chrome. There is no separate button to activate the dropdown as there was in Firefox 3.

Comment: Thx for clueing me into the drop-down menu on the back button.  I've attached a screenshot of the reload button's drop-down menu; it is the same for me on both Windows 7 and Kubuntu machines.

Comment: @13east The "Reload Tab Every" dropdown in your screenshot is not part of a standard Firefox install. It looks like part of the [Reload Every](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reloadevery/) Firefox Extension. It appears that in Firefox 4, this menu is also available from the tab context menu (in addition to the page context menu in Firefox 3) which might be where the confusion has arisen?

Comment: I don't have "Reload Every" extension installed on either of my machines; having this option in the tab context menu is enough, is there any way to get rid of the drop-down menu while still keeping the reload/stop combo button?

Comment: @13east: This feature (to reload a page every n seconds) is not part of Firefox's standard features (it's not part of the tab context menu) so you must have some kind of 3rd party extension installed that is enabling this feature?!

Comment: Thx for your help; this is part of Tab Mix Plus option.

Answer (score 0):

Just for record

1. to disable reload every drop-down aside of reload button you can either uncheck the `Tools > Tab Mix Plus Options > Events > Tab Features > Auto Reload > [ ] Show Reload Every menu on Reload button` preference, or set this via `about:config` with

   extensions.tabmix.reloadEvery.onReloadButton = false
2. history dropdown on back/forward buttons can be opened either by holding left mouse button for a while (as mentioned) or by right clicking them (at least on Windows platform).